# Is this a Matrix for AES, and why?

Tags: aes

My task is to  check if this S-BOX is an AES S-BOX. My Idear is, that you cant use it because 16 - 10 and 17 - 9 will give you the same output.

Given Matrix:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's obviously not the AES SBox.

In that SBox, input 0E maps to the value AB.  Your table has the horizontal row 7, and the vertical row 15 to give output AB - there is no obvious way to translate input 0E as "horizontal row 7, vertical row 15"

However, you asked if it were **an** AES SBox - that's rather like asking if a tower was "**an** Eiffel Tower"

Comment: Isn't there **an** Eiffel Tower in Las Vegas? :-)

Comment: No, in the same way that I didn't buy an Eiffel tower in the boutique *below* the Eiffel tower (well, my parents bought it at the time of course).